# How can I ignore / remove / exclude autocompletions in zsh?

Tags: zsh, autocomplete

I usually use `rs+[tab]` to get `rsync` but it's showing three options (on a new system):

```
➜  $ rs
     rsh       rsync     rsyslogd
```

I seldom use `rsh` or `rsyslogd` - how can I prevent these from appearing as matches in the autocompletion list in zsh?

Comment: http://zshwiki.org/home/examples/compsys/ignore

Comment: @jasonwryan - still confused - how would one use that to accomplish ignoring `rsh` and `rsyslogd` ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you don't want `rsh` and `rsyslog` to be ever completed in any situation just add the following into `.zshrc`:

```
zstyle ':completion:*' ignored-patterns 'rsh|rsyslog'
```

Comment: awesome - thank you. I knew it wasn't difficult in theory but was having a hard time finding an example of how to do this. ps: (for others) I did change `rsyslog` to `rsyslogd`